# Getting a syntax error when running the test.sh file "./test.sh: 36: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")"

Tags: server, bash, scripts

I'm getting this syntax error when running the test.sh file:

```
./test.sh: 36: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# WebHook
url="DiscordWebHook"
hostname="TestingSvr01"
PublicIP="My IP"

# check current disk usage
df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|loop' | awk '{ print $5 " " $6 }' | while read output;

# assign variables
do
  #echo $output
  used=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  USERNAME=\"${hostname}\"
  PUBLICIP=\"${PublicIP}\"
  msg_content=\"$message\"
  DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL="${url}"

  # if disk reached the threshold, send a notification to Discord #Infra. 
  if [ $used -ge 85 ]; then
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"used\": $used, \"partition\": $partition, \"username\": $USERNAME, \"IP\": $publicIP, \"content\": $msg_content}" $DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL
  else
    echo "${output}  failed"
  fi
exit 0
Done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Done` in the last line is case sensitive. `bash` is expecting `done`, so use `done` (all lowercase) instead.

Here are the results of checking your bash shell script at https://www.shellcheck.net/.

[image]

`PublicIP` in `PUBLICIP=\"${PublicIP}\"` does not match `publicIP` in `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"used": $used, "partition": $partition, "username": $USERNAME, "IP": $publicIP, "content": $msg_content}" $DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL` Use `PUBLICIP=\"${publicIP}\"` instead.

You can install ShellCheck in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install shellcheck` and run it with `shellcheck test.sh` ShellCheck would be a very convenient tool to use for checking your shell script because it points to the exact location of the error in each line where an error that it found is located.